# javascript object assignment throws an exception

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

im trying to build a javascript matrix as an object.

i tied :

```
var variations={}; 
variations["p1088"]["red"]["gen"]=1107;
variations["p1090"]["red"]["l"]=1288;
```

and

```
var variations={}; 
variations.p1088.red.gen=1107;
variations.p1090.red.gen=1288;
```

but both throws an exception

```
TypeError: variations.p1090 is undefined
```

whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you cannot assume that p1088, red, and gen are objects. This works:

```
// short version
var variations = { p1088: { red: { gen: 1107 } } };

// long version
var varations = {};
varations.p1088 = {};
varations.p1088.red = {};
varations.p1088.red.gen = 1077;
```

Answer (score 5):

Each subobject needs to be declared. So to get the first one set it would be

```
var variations = {};
variations.p1088 = {};
variations.p1088.red = {};
variations.p1088.red.gen = 1107;
```

Though, if I understand what you're trying to do, I would make variations an array of objects.

```
var variations = [];
variations[0] = {name: 'p1088',color:'red',gen:1007}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the error says, `variations.p1090` is undefined.  You never gave it a value.

```
var variations={}; 
variations.p1088={};
variations.p1088.red={};
variations.p1088.red.gen=1107;
```